# keep getting error when i call a const function with a const object in main

Tags: c++

header file:

```
#ifndef CONTMEM_H
#define CONTMEM_H

class Contmem {
public:
    Contmem(int a, int b, int c);

    int total;
    int mem;
    const int constmem;
    int printconst() const;
    const int constant;
    void print();
};

#endif // CONTMEM_H
```

Contmem.cpp file:

```
#include "Contmem.h"
#include <iostream> 

Contmem::Contmem(int a, int b, int c)
    : mem(a), constmem(b), constant(c)
{
    total = mem * constmem * constant;
}

void Contmem::print()
{
    std::cout << "This is my variable member " << mem << " and this is my constmem member " << constmem << "with the constant member" << constant << std::endl;  
}

int  Contmem::printconst() const
{
    return total;
    std::cout << "This is the total variable " << total << std::endl;
}
```

main function :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Contmem.h"

int main()
{
    Contmem cont(3, 4, 5);
    cont.print();
    const Contmem obj;
    obj.printconst();
}
```

error file:

```
|=== Build: Debug in CONST_&_MEMBER_INITIALIZER

 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| C:\C++

CODEBLOCK\CONST_&_MEMBER_INITIALIZER\main.cpp||

In function 'int  main()':| C:\C++

 CODEBLOCK\CONST_&_MEMBER_INITIALIZER\main.cpp|9|error: 

 no matching function for call to 'Contmem::Contmem()'| 

C:\C++  CODEBLOCK\CONST_&_MEMBER_INITIALIZER\Contmem.h|8|note: candidate:

 Contmem::Contmem(int, int, int)| C:\C++

 CODEBLOCK\CONST_&_MEMBER_INITIALIZER\Contmem.h|8|note:   candidate

 expects 3 arguments, 0 provided| C:\C++

 CODEBLOCK\CONST_&_MEMBER_INITIALIZER\Contmem.h|5|note: candidate:

 Contmem::Contmem(const Contmem&)| C:\C++

 CODEBLOCK\CONST_&_MEMBER_INITIALIZER\Contmem.h|5|note:   candidate

 expects 1 argument, 0 provided| ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0

 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Ask yourself, Which constructor should `const Contmem obj;` use?

Comment: This line `const Contmem obj` is trying to call the `Constmem` default constructor, which you do not have, you only have a constructor which takes arguments

Comment: Some of that code looked like it was formatted specifically to be misleading.

Comment: Seriously, you just have to read the error message _carefully_, and look at the line it mentions. Don't just glance at it and assume the error must be something else on a different line.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but am having difficulties implementing the default constructor..  the compiler stills throws some errors... somebody should help me with the implementation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const Contmem obj;
```

attempts to call the default constructor, `Contmem()`.

**BUT** because of:

```
Contmem::Contmem(int a, int b, int c)
    : mem(a), constmem(b), constant(c)
```

which has a mem-initializer and a `const` member, your default constructor **is** [*deleted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_default_constructor).

Thus, compiler can't match that statement to any of the existing constructor, since only your mem-initializer constructor exists.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a **default constructor** for your class. You only have this one

```
Contmem::Contmem(int a, int b, int c)
    : mem(a), constmem(b), constant(c)
{
    total = mem * constmem * constant;
}
```

but here

```
int main()
{
    Contmem cont(3, 4, 5);
    cont.print();
    const Contmem obj; // <--here
    obj.printconst();
}
```

you are trying to construct a new `Contmem` object without passing those 3 arguments

---

Actually, those compiler errors are telling you what the real problem is.

Comment: perhaps a follow-up question is, what happened to the implicit default constructor?